# How to use gsub to fix case-defined multiple spaces and broken lines?

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I used `pdftools` to convert some pdf documents to txt. This is a part of the output (it's not so bad)

```
REPÚBLICA DE CHILE         PADRON ELECTORAL AUDITADO       ELECCIONES PRESIDENCIAL, PARLAMENTARIAS y de CONSEJEROS REGIONALES 2017             REGISTROS:       2.421
SERVICIO ELECTORAL         REGIÓN     : ARICA Y PARINACOTA                                    COMUNA: GENERAL LAGOS                                    PÁGINA 1 de 38
                           PROVINCIA  : PARINACOTA
NOMBRE                                                     C.IDENTIDAD SEXO    DOMICILIO ELECTORAL                             CIRCUNSCRIPCIÓN                   MESA
AGUILERA SIMPERTIGUE JUDITH ALEJANDRA                         13.638.826-6 MUJ PUEBLO DE TACORA S N VISVIRI                    GENERAL LAGOS                        4M
AGUILERA ZENTENO PATRICIA ALEJANDRA                           16.223.938-4 MUJ PUEBLO DE GUACOLLO S N CERCANO A                GENERAL LAGOS                        5M
AGUIRRE CHOQUE MARCOS JULIO                                   15.000.385-7 VAR CIRCUNSCRIPCION
                                                                               CALLE  TORREALBA DE  VISVIRI
                                                                                                 CASA  N° 4 PUEBLO DE VISVIRI  GENERAL LAGOS                        7V
```

So I'm doing this to clean this and convert it into formatted tsv:

```
test = read_lines("file.txt")

test2 = test[!grepl("REP\u00daBLICA",test)]
test2 = test2[!grepl("SERVICIO",test2)]
test2 = test2[!grepl("NOMBRE",test2)]
test2 = test2[!grepl("PROVINCIA",test2)]

test2 = gsub("\\.", "", test2)
test2 = gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", test2, perl=TRUE)
```

and the output is:

```
ABRIGO PIZARRO PATRICIO ESTEBAN 16024716-9 VAR PUEB ALCERRECA GENERAL LAGOS 5V
ABURTO VELASCO ESTHER MARISOL 13005517-6 MUJ VILLA INDUSTRIAL GENERAL LAGOS 2M
ACEVEDO MONTT SEBASTIAN ANDRES 17829470-9 VAR CALLE RAFAEL TORREALBA N° 3 PUEBLO DE VISVIRI GENERAL LAGOS 3V
ACHILLO BLAS ADOLFO ARTURO 13008044-8 VAR VISURI GENERAL LAGOS 7V
```

I've read some posts and I'm not sure how to implement:

1. Something like `gsub("(?<=[\\s+])[0-9]", "\t", test2, perl=TRUE)`, this is to replace multiple spaces followed by a number by tab followed by a number
2. How to move broken lines to the end of the previous line, such as line 8 in the above sample that starts with multiple spaces.

Fixing (1) and (2) would return this:

```
ABRIGO PIZARRO PATRICIO ESTEBAN \t 16024716-9 \t VAR \t PUEB ALCERRECA \t GENERAL LAGOS \t 5V
ABURTO VELASCO ESTHER MARISOL \t 13005517-6 \t MUJ \t VILLA INDUSTRIAL \t GENERAL LAGOS \t 2M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You can use the words "VAR" and "MUJ" as key-words for splitting:

```
x <- "AGUILERA SIMPERTIGUE JUDITH ALEJANDRA                         13.638.826-6 MUJ PUEBLO DE TACORA S N VISVIRI                    GENERAL LAGOS                        4M"
strsplit(x, "\\s{2,}|\\s(?=\\bMUJ\\b)|(?<=\\bMUJ\\b)\\s|\\s(?=\\bVAR\\b)|(?<=\\bVAR\\b)\\s", perl = TRUE)
```

The result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "AGUILERA SIMPERTIGUE JUDITH ALEJANDRA" "13.638.826-6"                          "MUJ"                                  
[4] "PUEBLO DE TACORA S N VISVIRI"          "GENERAL LAGOS"                         "4M"
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works and if you can modify the data you could use real key-words and assure they are unique.

(2) An easy solution would be to check rows length and move values up if the row is too short

Comment: thanks ! I'm still trying to figure out how to merge lines that start with blank spaces